# Regex to match s3 link

Tags: python, regex, amazon-s3

I have a s3 object in the following format.

```
https://s3-{region}.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{environment}/{keyname}
```

I need a regex which can fetch me the individual variables from a s3 link. Currently I have the following regex.

```
r"https\:\/\/s3\-(\w+)\.amazonaws\.com\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$"
```

But it returns None.

Comment: Have you tested this out in something like http://regex101.com? It [works fine on `'https://s3-region.amazonaws.com/bucket/env/key'`](https://regex101.com/r/TZTkUE/1/) so you should reconsider whether `\w+` is appropriate for the values you're getting.

Comment: what if you leave out the dollar sign at the end?

Comment: Oh. Thanks jon. The region name had `-` in it. Modified the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
https?://s3-
(?P<region>[^.]+).amazonaws.com/
(?P<bucket>[^/]+)/
(?P<environment>[^/]+)/
(?P<keyname>.*)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Y8Snet/2).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    https?://s3-
    (?P<region>[^.]+).amazonaws.com/
    (?P<bucket>[^/]+)/
    (?P<environment>[^/]+)/
    (?P<keyname>.*)''', re.VERBOSE)

links = rx.findall(your_string_here)
```